# Can Kibana or other Elastic product import dynamic flow of images and view on Dashboard?

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

My purpose is to import a stream of dynamic data from a server and, in addition, display in the center of the dashboard a window that shows the update of a real-time object (through a series of photographs taken by a camera and shown in succession within a widget).

Is it possible to do it with an Elastic product or directly with Kibana using a special JSON script (or a plugin)?